# WHM enable PHP PDO library

Tags: php, pdo, cpanel, vps, whm

I just switched hosts from a shared to a vps host and I am configuring my WHM account. I want to be able to use the PHP PDO library. I know how to get to the apache update form and locate the pdo section. The only problem is that there are two options, a pdo check box that reads

> Includes SQLite support. MySQL support is available. If you plan on installing or updating >PDO drivers (freetds, oracle, etc) via PECL you might want to skip this option as PECL will >install the version of PDO it has. This option will make the following changes to your >profile prior to the build:
>   Enables:
>    SQLite3

and a PDO_MYSQL box that reads

> This option will make the following changes to your profile prior to the build:
>   Enables:
>    PDO

I do not know which option to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one, the first is to enable SQLite; I'm guessing you wanna use MySQL ?

Comment: I found I had to enable both. When I tried only selecting the second one and building, I got an error saying the first must be enabled and "cannot be skipped.